# How to import C# syntax colors from Visual Studio Code to Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017

I'd want to use Visual Studio Code's colors for C# (Omnisharp) in Visual Studio - How can I export them?

Here's comparison:

[image: first]
[image: second]

Comment: I think you can't

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can't. But, you can use [Viasfora](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomasRestrepo.Viasfora) to improve syntax coloration in VS.

#### Rainbow Braces

> Colorize `()/[]/{}` based on depth!
>   [image: Rainbow Braces]

#### Keyword classification

> - Colorize flow-control keywords
>     [image: Flow Control Keywords]
> - Colorize LINQ keywords
>     [image: LINQ Keywords]
> - Colorize visibility keywords
>     [image: Visibility keywords]

#### String colorization

> - Highlighting escape sequences in strings
>     [image: Escape Sequences]
> - Highlighting C/C++ format specifiers in strings
>     [image: C format specifiers]